# global section of inverse image and etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology, grothendieck-topologies

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. If it is needed, we can assume that $X,Y$ are quasi-compact and quasi-separated, and $f$ is affine. Consider the two small etale sites $X_{et}$ and $Y_{et}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an abelian sheaf over $Y_{et}$. My question is about the canonical homomorphism:
$$\varphi:\ H^q(Y_{et};Y,\mathcal{F})\to H^q(X_{et};X,f^*\mathcal{F})$$
which is induced by $\Gamma(Y,\mathcal{F})\to \Gamma(Y,f_*f^*\mathcal{F})=\Gamma(X,f^*\mathcal{F})$.

Is $\varphi$ an isomorphism?

I tried to show that $\Gamma(Y,-)=\Gamma(X,-)\circ f^*$, but I failed. I can only show that $\Gamma(Y,-)=\Gamma(X,-)\circ f^*$ when $f$ is etale, which is a trivial result. And I also know that this will be true if we consider the cohomology of quasi-coherent sheafs and assume that $f:X\to Y$ is an affine morphism since $f_*$ is exact.

Is this true for affine morphism between quasi-compact, quasi-separated schemes? And general cases? Can you help me?

Comment: Why would you think this is the case? What if $Y=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, $X=\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{Z}}$, $\mathcal{F}=\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}$, and $q=1$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Could you please tell me how $f: X\to Y$ maps? I mean, what is the ring hom $\mathbb{C}[x]\to \mathbb{Z}[x,x^{-1}]$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis In fact I only know that this will be true in the category of quasi-coherent etale sheaves when $f$ is affine, since in this case, $H^q_{Zar}(X,M)\cong H^q_{et}(X,M_{et})$.

Comment: sorry $X$ should have been $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{Z}}$, and the map is the inclusion. In this case $H^1(Y,\mathcal{F})$ is zero, but $H^1(X,\mathcal{F})$ is non-zero.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for your comment!